# Split Math Formula by Operators but keep operators

Tags: php, regex

I'm looking to split the following strings based upon the operator between them.  If there is parenthesis then we have to keep the entire parenthesis together.

Here's the types of strings I will have.

```
(1.25*1.5)-(10.5/2.15625)
(1.25*1.5)+10.75
1.25*(10.5/10.75)
1.25/10.5
```

The desired output I'm looking for is this

```
array(){
    [0]=>
    string = "(1.25*1.5)"
    [1]=>
    string = "-"
    [2]=>
    string = "(10.5/2.15625)"
}

array(){
    [0]=>
    string = "(1.25*1.5)"
    [1]=>
    string = "+"
    [2]=>
    string = "10.75"
}

array(){
    [0]=>
    string = "1.25"
    [1]=>
    string = "*"
    [2]=>
    string = "(10.5/10.75)"
}

array(){
    [0]=>
    string = "1.25"
    [1]=>
    string = "/"
    [2]=>
    string = "10.5"
}
```

this is what I have so far.

```
$expression_parts = preg_split('~([<>=]+)~', $expression, NULL, 
PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY ) ;
```

Comment: What if you have nested parentheses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll show you a new trick `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` this time.  This technique is used to match and disqualify targeted substrings.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/TEa3M))

```
$strings=[
    '(1.25*1.5)-(10.5/2.15625)',
    '(1.25*1.5)+10.75',
    '1.25*(10.5/10.75)',
    '1.25/10.5'
];
foreach ($strings as $string) {
//                                                  vvvvvvvv-capture and retain non-numeric characters (delimiters)
    var_export(preg_split('~\([^)]*\)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|([^\d.])~', $string, 0, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE));
//                          ^^^^^^^^^-match and disqualify parentheticals
    echo "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => '(1.25*1.5)',
  1 => '-',
  2 => '(10.5/2.15625)',
)
array (
  0 => '(1.25*1.5)',
  1 => '+',
  2 => '10.75',
)
array (
  0 => '1.25',
  1 => '*',
  2 => '(10.5/10.75)',
)
array (
  0 => '1.25',
  1 => '/',
  2 => '10.5',
)
```

This will also perform very well on your input strings:

```
preg_match_all('~\([^)]+\)|\d+(?:\.\d+)?|.~', $string, $out) ? $out[0] : []

~                #pattern delimiter
\([^)]+\)        #match parenthetical expression (does not account for nested parentheticals)
|                #or
\d+(?:\.\d+)?    #match integers or floats (notice the ? makes the trailing portion optional
|                #or
.                #match one non-newline character that isn't caught by an earlier "alternative"
~                #pattern delimiter
```

Comment: Unfortunetly, I wasn't joking about being learning disabled. Believe me, I'm trying really hard to understand. I tried a pattern similar to your second suggestion but kept getting errors around `(? )`.  But thanks again for being my hero.  I'm going to study these patterns.

Comment: so in this pattern `([^)]*\)`, why are you negating the `^)`

Comment: I would like to encourage you to upvote all of the other answers as well.  trincot's is separately valuable because he is extending the pattern to nested expressions too.

Comment: `\([^)]*\)` the more you see high quality regex patterns, the more you will see this technique -- it is the optimized version of `\(.*?\)`.  `[^something]` is a "Negated Character Class".  When you tell the regex engine exactly what you _aren't_ looking for and allow it to match "greedily" it can run faster.  Now that we have give you several answers to your recent questions, take some time to visit some regex tutorial pages and read up on the language and its capabilities.  Time spent developing your regex knowledge is never time wasted.

Comment: you sir, are my master ~bow~

Comment: I am happy to help, but slow down between questions.  You _NEED_ to do some more research before asking a question on StackOverflow or people will potentially downvote you for being "lazy".  If you use SO like a crutch, you don't actually get "better".  You are welcome to comment me any time if you have tiny questions regarding any of my answers.

Comment: I hear you there.  If I wasn't stuck on all of this already for 3 days I wouldn't post.  I'm running out of time on this project so getting it done is a necessity. You've given me a lot of meat to chew on.  For that I am thankful. It takes me a long time to learn something but when it finally clicks, then I can master it.  Right now I am a white belt, trying to learn black belt stuff.

Answer (score 1):

With `preg_split()` function and specific regex pattern:

```
$arr = ['(1.25*1.5)-(10.5/2.15625)', '(1.25*1.5)+10.75',
        '1.25*(10.5/10.75)', '1.25/10.5'
        ];

foreach ($arr as $exp) {
    $result = preg_split('/([\/*+-])(?:(?=(?:\(\d+.+\)|\d+(?:\.\d+)?)$))/', $exp,
                         0, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    print_r($result);
}
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => (1.25*1.5)
    [1] => -
    [2] => (10.5/2.15625)
)
Array
(
    [0] => (1.25*1.5)
    [1] => +
    [2] => 10.75
)
Array
(
    [0] => 1.25
    [1] => *
    [2] => (10.5/10.75)
)
Array
(
    [0] => 1.25
    [1] => /
    [2] => 10.5
)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Regex**: [`\([^\)]+\)|[-+*\/]|(?:\d+(?:\.\d+))`](https://regex101.com/r/HAz4bn/1)

Details:

- `(?:)` Non-capturing group
- `\d` Matches a digit (equal to `[0-9]`)
- `[^]` Match a single character NOT present in the list
- `+` Matches between one and unlimited times
- `|` Or

**PHP code**:

```
$strings=['(1.25*1.5)-(10.5/2.15625)', '(1.25*1.5)+10.75', '1.25*10.5/10.75)', '1.25/10.5'];

foreach($strings as $string){
    preg_match_all('~\([^)]+\)|[-+*/]|(?:\d+(?:\.\d+))~', $string, $matches);
    print_r($matches[0]);
}
```

**Output**:

```
Array
(
    [0] => (1.25*1.5)
    [1] => -
    [2] => (10.5/2.15625)
)
Array
(
    [0] => (1.25*1.5)
    [1] => +
    [2] => 10.75
)
Array
(
    [0] => 1.25
    [1] => *
    [2] => (10.5/10.75)
)
Array
(
    [0] => 1.25
    [1] => /
    [2] => 10.5
)
```

Comment: I see that you are enjoying these regex questions.  Please always endeavor to minimize/eliminate escaping in your patterns as a matter of best practice.  This will result in a pattern with greater brevity and improved readability. Specific to this case, if you make `~` your pattern delimiter, you can avoid escaping `/` inside your character class and your `)` in the first character classes doesn't require escaping.